# unable to adjust iFrame size

Tags: html, css

I have an iFrame on my website for a vimeo video that I don't want to be full screen. It's taking up the entire size of the page at 1046 x 588.38 px.

I have tried adjusting the height and width in the embed code to no avail. If I change the percentages in CSS it will break or become too small and still not respond to the height or width values.

HTML is as follows:

```
<section class="vid">
    <div class="responsive">
        <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://player.vimeo.com/" frameborder="0"
            allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</section>
```

The possible offending css is as follows:

```
.responsive {
width: 100%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
position: relative; }

.responsive iframe {
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to use width and height in `.responsive iframe`,
you can set the width and height inside the `iframe` element

```css
.responsive {
width: 100%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
position: relative; }

.responsive iframe {
display: block;
position: absolute;
/* width: 100%;
height: 100%;  */
}
```

```html
<section class="vid">
        <div class="responsive">
            <iframe width="640" height="200" src="https://player.vimeo.com/"                       frameborder="0"allow="autoplay"></iframe>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. That fixed it. I'm a newbie to web dev- thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome ,happy to help you